# Is it possible to view passwords through Terminal?

Tags: terminal, command-line, password, keychain

Does anyone know how to view passwords in Terminal? Maybe by accessing the Keychain data or something? I want to be able to view passwords in Terminal with just a series of commands.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out the `security` command.  You can get detailed information about its use by reading its man entry `man security`

An in-depth article on the `security`command is [here](http://blog.macromates.com/2006/keychain-access-from-shell/).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we are talking about an internet password of a site. Then you would input:

```
security find-internet-password -gs www.paypal.com
```

On the other hand if we are talking about a generic password, we use the command

```
security find-generic-password -gs www.test_site.com
```

where,

-g: is used to display the password for the item found

-a account_name: matches the account name given

-s server: matches teh server string

sources:

http://blog.macromates.com/2006/keychain-access-from-shell/
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/security.1.html