# How to find out what the Wi-Fi password is, of the network that I'm connected to, without the admin password?

Tags: terminal, wifi, password

I logged on to a Wi-Fi network on my friend's computer and they forgot their admin password. They want me to find out the password, but I can't get into the keychain. But I am still connected to the network, that they want to connect to on another computer. I heard there was a way to do it in the terminal but I can't find it. What is the command line? All i know is that there is a command line in terminal that allows you to view the password of the wifi network you are currently connected to.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you do not have your computer's password nor the wifi password?

Comment: what "other" device you are trying to connect to?

Comment: Relevant: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13387/is-it-possible-to-view-passwords-through-terminal http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150297/view-passwords-of-all-wi-fi-networks-my-mac-has-connected-to-in-the-past

Comment: The admin password for a router and the password to connect to a wifi network are not the same thing. It's also unclear if you mean the computer's admin password or the router's. If you want to know how to view the connection password to a network you have previously connected to, the second link that Bart posted above provides an answer to that. You will, however, need an administrator's login for the Mac to do so. Resetting the admin password for the router is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: Who are "they" ?

Comment: Why can't you or your friend go in the Keychain? The Keychain is the place to go for finding back saved passwords.

Comment: @tubedogg — Resetting the admin password of the router is in the scope of this site if the router is an AirPort device or a Time Capsule.

Answer (score 1):

You can view your own keychain via the /Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app

None of this is possible without an admin password.

The command line is accessible via /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app